# IBM Cloud Secrets Manager: Unable to create an arbitrary secret

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-secrets-manager

I am trying the following API request for IBM Cloud Secrets Manager, but it fails:

```
curl -X POST "https://{instance_ID}.{region}.secrets-manager.appdomain.cloud/api/v1/secrets/arbitrary"   -H "Authorization: Bearer $IAM_TOKEN"   -H "Accept: application/json"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{
    "metadata": {
      "collection_type": "application/vnd.ibm.secrets-manager.secret+json",
      "collection_total": 1
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "example-arbitrary-secret",
          "description": "Extended description for my secret.",
          "secret_group_id": "432b91f1-ff6d-4b47-9f06-82debc236d90",
          "payload: "secret-data",
          "expiration_date": "2030-12-31T00:00:00Z",
          "labels": [
            "dev",
            "us-south"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a missing double-quote after `payload`...

```
curl -X POST "https://{instance_ID}.{region}.secrets-manager.appdomain.cloud/api/v1/secrets/arbitrary"   -H "Authorization: Bearer $IAM_TOKEN"   -H "Accept: application/json"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{
    "metadata": {
      "collection_type": "application/vnd.ibm.secrets-manager.secret+json",
      "collection_total": 1
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "example-arbitrary-secret",
          "description": "Extended description for my secret.",
          "secret_group_id": "432b91f1-ff6d-4b47-9f06-82debc236d90",
          "payload": "secret-data",
          "expiration_date": "2030-12-31T00:00:00Z",
          "labels": [
            "dev",
            "us-south"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }'
```